# Can't access nodejs server on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance which I am using for my node js application. I cannot access any application page on the server.
I wrote this simple code solely for testing purposes but I cannot access even this from my browser.

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, ()=>  {
    console.log('listening');
});

app.get('/',(req,res)=>  {
    res.send('hi');
});
```

On navigating to http://:3000, I should be able to see "hi" written but the request times out. 
Here are my security group configs : 
[image]

Comment: Did you tried to use the correct ip http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 ?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru yeah, I did. Gives the "site cannot be reached" page.

Comment: does it work if you try to access from the instance ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Not sure how to do this. Can you help me out a bit. I am a noobie in using aws

Comment: just ssh into your ec2 instance and run a curl command against your website like `curl http://localhost:3000` then `curl http://<privateip>:3000`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I did curl to `http://localhost:3000` and it works. But when I try in browser from my computer it doesn't. Any ideas? I did put in my security group inbound rules, `3000`  for `Custom TCP` and I set source to anywhere. screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2U24qUn.png

Comment: I also did `netstat -tulnp` and it seems `:::3000` is open but only on `tcp6`, do i need it in `tcp` too? How can I do this? Screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/9jZVZH0.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved the problem with some help.
Since the port available to me was port 80, so I just forwarded the port 8080 to port 80 via. port forwarding and it worked out.
Sharing the link from where I found the solution:[installing nodejs and forwarding port on aws](http://www.lauradhamilton.com/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-web-server-on-amazon-ec2)

Comment: after uncommenting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and checked if its enable by `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` it still returned 0 but I still proceeded on `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`and `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT`, 
`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` and now my aws node instance can be accessed to its public Public IPV4. Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 5):

My code (shown below) is a bit different, but I was having the same problem with connecting from a remote browser:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

What I had to do was replace const hostname with the complete AWS server IP: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/

Make sure you have port 3000 open in your security group, or this will not work.

I was then able to connect to the NodeJS server from my browser on my PC.

Hope this helps. The corrected code is shown below (replace the x's with your actual IP address. You can get this on your EC2 dashboard.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = 'http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I got the code for this NodeJS server from:

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-node-js-and-nmp-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/

Comment: This actually worked for me. I wonder why...
I tried putting the public ID and localhost and 127.0.0.1 and nothing worked.
But the public DNS works. This was for a server with EJS

Comment: For connections from external networks or sources you can use 0.0.0.0